# Spark SQL - Reading JSON using JSON Schema (official standard for schema)

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks, apache-spark-2.0

Is it possible to use an existing JSON schema (file), defined as per the standard:

http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-core.html,

to explicitily declare the schema for a JSON dataframe?  If so are there any examples?  We have many json schema files defining our JSON events, would be nice to be able to allow a DF to reuse these?

Cheers